# How to fetch online users -MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column `last_activity_time` in my `users` table and I want to select users whose last_activity_time is within the last 5 minutes. In this regard I need to convert column `last_activity_time` to UNIX_TIMESTAMP format so that I can compare it with the current date and time `strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"))`

I tried the SQL to select that but it triggers error of an unknown column `last_activity`.

It is true I don't have a column like that in table but I created that column with as alias

What is wrong with my SQL and how do I fix it?

```
$sql    = "SELECT  id,firstname,
                lastname,
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_activity_time) AS last_activity 
                FROM $main_table WHERE 
                (last_activity + 5) > ".strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s'))."

                ";  
$query  =   mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `WHERE` to `HAVING`, cause in mysql you can not use column alias in `WHERE` statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT
            id,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_activity_time) AS last_activity 
        FROM $main_table
        HAVING (last_activity + 5) > ".strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s'))."
       ";
```

Or you can just use full functional column in `WHERE`:

```
$sql = "SELECT
            id,
            firstname,
            lastname,
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_activity_time) AS last_activity 
        FROM $main_table
        WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_activity_time) + 5) > ".strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s'))."
       ";
```

Comment: Or, to be ANSI compliant, just repeat `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(...)` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thank you. It worked for me... i think i need to learning about the SQL clause HAVING

Comment: please help...how do I calculate 5 minutes in SQL or php should I do like: strtotime("5 minutes")..because the +  5 is not working as I expect

Comment: @jamesOduro Hint: [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Comment: What exactly should I do??..am confuse with the documentation DATE_ADD..I tried this: DATE_ADD(last_activity,INTERVAL '5:0' MINUTE_SECOND) but not working for me

Comment: I have done  it with this. 1 is equal to 1 SECOND so 5 minutes will be: (last_activity + (60*5))

Comment: Just `DATE_ADD(last_activity, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`. @jamesOduro